# How to get the next n bits with Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to read ID3v2 info from an mp3 file. Part of that is reading flags. `f.gets n` gets me `n` bytes, but I need `n` bits.

Comment: 8 bits to a byte.

Comment: I understand the a byte consists of 8 bits, I'm not sure how that helps though.

Comment: It's pretty simple arithmetic.  You want to read 8 bits, read 1 byte, you want 16 bits, read 2 bytes, etc.

Comment: How does one then test the individual value of those bits?

Comment: I assumed the question implied I wanted to get their values.

Answer (score 3):

Read a single byte then use `byte.bit(7)` down to `byte.bit(0)` to check whether a bit is set. This is nicer and more explicit than bitmasks.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach based on [bit masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)#Querying_the_status_of_a_bit) seems to work fine for me:

```
while input = gets 1 # get one char of input
  x = input.bytes[0] # convert it to numeric byte value
  # In the following, (7 - i) picks bits from left to right...
  8.times { |i| print ((x >> (7 - i)) & 1) } # shift, bit mask, and print bit
  puts # each byte on a separate line
end
```

input "abc" followed by `ctrl-d` on a new line (or `ctrl-z` for Windows) produces

```
01100001  # a is ascii 97
01100010  # b is ascii 98
01100011  # c is ascii 99
00001010  # line feed
```

without the descriptive comments, obviously.

This also works for non-ascii input, such as "фыв":

```
11010001
10000100
11010001
10001011
11010000
10110010
00001010
```

I have printed the results, but you can use the bits however you like.

---

Drawing on Julien Portalier's response and the comment from RX14, the following is clearer:

```
while byte = STDIN.read_byte # get one byte of input at a time
  7.downto(0) { |i| print byte.bit(i) } # extract bits left-to-right
  puts # put a newline after each byte
end
```

Comment: FYI, you should use `io.read_byte` to read a byte from an IO, instead of using `gets` and `bytes[0]`. Strings in crystal are UTF-8, so your method could read multiple bytes and discard some data if the input isn't ASCII.

Comment: @RX14 As demonstrated, the original works with non-ascii.  Using `read_byte` improves the readability though.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. `gets 1` does count by bytes instead of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read `IO`s bit-by-bit, you have to read whole numbers of bytes and extract bits from that using masking. Almost all protocols are designed with that in mind, and allow you to read n number of bytes then split those n bytes into fields.